# How to convert snake_case to camelCase?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have something like

```
data = {
   'id':'123',
   'employee_name': 'John',
   'employee_type': 'new'  
}

var newObj = _.mapValues(data, function (value, key) {
     var t = _.camelCase(key);
     console.log(t) -> shows employeeName and employeeType

     return _.camelCase(key);
});
```

I was expecting my newObj will become

```
data = {
   'id':'123',
   'employeeName': 'John',
   'employeeType': 'new'  
}
```

Comment: **For a recursive solution (nested Objects) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75927783/7910454**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `_.mapKeys()` instead of `_.mapValues()`:

```js
var data = {
   'id': '123',
   'employee_name': 'John',
   'employee_type': 'new'  
};

var newObj = _.mapKeys(data, (value, key) => _.camelCase(key));

console.log('newObj: ', newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to ignore the redundant `value` param, you can use [`_.rearg()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#rearg) on `_.camelCase()` to generate a function that takes the 2nd param (the `key`) instead of the 1st param (the `value`).

```js
var data = {
   'id': '123',
   'employee_name': 'John',
   'employee_type': 'new'  
};

var newObj = _.mapKeys(data, _.rearg(_.camelCase, 1));

console.log('newObj: ', newObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you must have lodash version 3.8.0 or later - mapValues introduced in version 2.4.0 ... so you can have one without the other

Answer (score 58):

replacing snake_case or kebab-case to camelCase only for string (ES6+):

```
const snakeToCamel = str =>
  str.toLowerCase().replace(/([-_][a-z])/g, group =>
    group
      .toUpperCase()
      .replace('-', '')
      .replace('_', '')
  );
```

result:

```
console.log(snakeToCamel('TO_CAMEL')) //toCamel
console.log(snakeToCamel('to_camel')) //toCamel
console.log(snakeToCamel('TO-CAMEL')) //toCamel
console.log(snakeToCamel('to-camel')) //toCamel
```

Comment: Can be simplified to: str.toLowerCase().replace(/[-_][a-z]/g, (group) => group.slice(-1).toUpperCase());

Comment: If numbers can occur, like in my case, then use str.toLowerCase().replace(/[-_][a-z0-9]/g, (group) => group.slice(-1).toUpperCase());

Comment: thanks, this is great but you could also arguably make the function more robust by doing a check right away for dash or underscore characters and early return if found.  Otherwise a caller may call the function with something like 'camelCase' and get a result of 'camelcase' because there is always that one person who will misuse your function.  So something like ```if ( !(/[_-]/).test(str) ) return str;``` on the first line may do the trick.

Answer (score 15):

You can also easily create your own function for that:

```js
function camelCase(obj) {
  var newObj = {};
  for (d in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(d)) {
      newObj[d.replace(/(\_\w)/g, function(k) {
        return k[1].toUpperCase();
      })] = obj[d];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

var data = {
  'id': '123',
  'employee_name': 'John',
  'employee_type': 'new'
}

console.log(camelCase(data));
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's how to do it in native Javascript...

```js
let data = {
   'id':'123',
   'employee_name': 'John',
   'employee_type': 'new'  
}

// #1 simple function which converts a string from snake case to camel case ...
const snakeToCamel = s => s.replace(/(_\w)/g, k => k[1].toUpperCase())

// #2 create new data object with camelCase keys...
data = Object.entries(data).reduce((x,[k,v]) => (x[snakeToCamel(k)]=v) && x, {})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 7):

## TypeScript

As always, nobody asked for typescript version, but here it is, please don't beat me ^-^.

### Without `_`, No `RegExp`

- I split functions in two modules but you can keep them outside with proper naming
- I put `never` to mark out that the type is actually correct since TS doesn't always know if it is.
- You still can use `_` and get code shorter but I wanted to breakdown the process.

```
module CaseTransform {
  export type Snake = Lowercase<`${string}_${string}`>
  export type Camel = Capitalize<string> | `${Capitalize<string>}${Capitalize<string>}`

  export type SnakeToCamel<S extends string> = S extends `${infer Start}_${infer Rest}` ? `${Start}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamel<Rest>>}` : S
  type SnakeToCamel__TEST__ = SnakeToCamel<"my_account_profile"> // myAccountProfile

  export function capitalize<S extends string>(string: S): Capitalize<S> {
    if (string.length === 0) return "" as never

    return (string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)) as never
  }
  export function snakeToCamel<S extends string>(string: S): SnakeToCamel<S> {
    const [start, ...rest] = string.split("_")

    return (start + rest.map(capitalize).join("")) as never
  }
  const snakeToCamel__TEST__ = snakeToCamel("ASD_asd_asdad_")
}

module ObjectTransform {
  export function snakeToCamel<O extends object, K extends keyof O>(object: O): { [P in K as (P extends CaseTransform.Snake ? CaseTransform.SnakeToCamel<P> : P)]: O[P] } {
    return Object
      .entries(object)
      .reduce((result, [key, value]) => ({
        ...result,
        [CaseTransform.snakeToCamel(key)]: value
      }), {}) as never
  }
}

const sample = {
  id: 123,
  employee_name: "John",
  employee_type: "new",

  camelCase: "123",
  PascalCase: "123"
}
const __TEST__ = ObjectTransform.snakeToCamel(sample)
```

#### Note

If you want all characters (even abbreviations) to be in lowercase, put `.toLowercase()` after `string` AND change `SnakeToCamel` type to

```
type SnakeToCamel<S extends string> = S extends `${infer Start}_${infer Rest}` ? `${Lowercase<Start>}${Capitalize<SnakeToCamel<Rest>>}` : Lowercase<S>
```

**Easy!**

#### Typings Result

[image: Sample with snake case keys before transformation]
[image: Sample with camel case keys after transformation]

#### JavaScript Playground

```js
function capitalize(string) {
  if (string.length === 0) return ""

  return (string[0].toUpperCase() + string.slice(1))
}
function snakeToCamel(string){
  const [start, ...rest] = string.split("_")

  return (start + rest.map(capitalize).join(""))
}
const snakeToCamel__TEST__ = snakeToCamel("ASD_asd_asdad_")
console.log(snakeToCamel__TEST__)

function objectKeysSnakeToCamel(object) {
  return Object
    .entries(object)
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) => ({
      ...result,
      [snakeToCamel(key)]: value
    }), {})
}

const sample = {
  id: 123,
  employee_name: "John",
  employee_type: "new",

  camelCase: "123",
  PascalCase: "123"
}
const __TEST__ = objectKeysSnakeToCamel(sample)
console.log(__TEST__)
```

Answer (score 5):

For my use case I needed (or wanted) a function that would handle any arbitrary json object, including nested objects, arrays, etc. Came up with this, seems to be working so far:

```
const fromSnakeToCamel = (data) => {
  if (_.isArray(data)) {
    return _.map(data, fromSnakeToCamel);
  }

  if (_.isObject(data)) {
    return _(data)
      .mapKeys((v, k) => _.camelCase(k))
      .mapValues((v, k) => fromSnakeToCamel(v))
      .value();
  }

  return data;
}
```

Note that if it's not an array or an object, I just return the data because I only actually want to convert keys. Anyway, hope this helps someone

Answer (score 5):

```
  camelCase(str) {
    return str
      .toLowerCase()
      .replace(/([-_][a-z])/g, (ltr) => ltr.toUpperCase())
      .replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '')
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

These are all good answers, but they did not fit what I needed. I like Ashish's answer because it handles nested objects, but what if there are underscores in the data that you want?  So, here is a varient on Bambam's answer to make it recursive, because lodash can sometimes be a pain.

```
function toCamelCase (obj) {
    let rtn = obj
    if(!rtn) {
        return rtn
    } else if (typeof (obj) === 'object') {
        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            rtn = obj.map(toCamelCase)
        } else {
            rtn = {}
            for (let key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     const newKey = key.replace(/(_\w)/g, k => k[1].toUpperCase())
                     rtn[newKey] = toCamelCase(obj[key])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn
}
```

Comment: If the value of a key is `null`, it will fail because `typeof null === 'object'`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another answer using simple for loop.

```
var data = {
   'id': '123',
   'employee_name': 'John',
   'employee_type': 'new'  
};

var output = {}
for (var key in data) {
  output[_.camelCase(key)] = data[key];
}
```

Comment: `data[_.camelCase(key)]` should that be `output [_.camelCase(key)]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will definitely work as expected.

```js
const helpers = {};

helpers.camelize = function(str) {
    return str.trim().replace(/[A-Z]+/g, (letter, index) => {
        return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : '_' + letter.toLowerCase();
    }).replace(/(.(\_|-|\s)+.)/g, function(subStr) {
        return subStr[0]+(subStr[subStr.length-1].toUpperCase());
    });
}


helpers.camelizeKeys = function(data) {
    const result = {};
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
        result[helpers.camelize(key)] = val;
    }
    return result;
}

helpers.camelizeNestedKeys = function(dataObj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataObj).trim().replace(/("\w+":)/g, function(keys) {
        return keys.replace(/[A-Z]+/g, (letter, index) => {
            return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : '_' + letter.toLowerCase();
        }).replace(/(.(\_|-|\s)+.)/g, function(subStr) {
            return subStr[0]+(subStr[subStr.length-1].toUpperCase());
        });
    }));
}


const data = {
    'id':'123',
    'employee_name': 'John',
    'employee_type': 'new'  
};

const nestedData = {
    'id':'123',
    'employee_name': 'John',
    'employee_type': 'new',
    'exployee_projects': [
        {"project_name": "test1", "project_year": 2004},
        {"project_name": "test2", "project_year": 2004}
    ]
};


// Few camelize Examples
const str1 = "banana_orange_apple_mango";
const str2 = "banana-orange-apple-mango";
const str3 = "banana orange apple mango";
const str4 = "BANANA Orange APPLE-mango";
const str5 = "banana 5orange apple #mango";
const str6 = "banana__orange-_apple5-#mango";

console.log(helpers.camelize(str1));
console.log(helpers.camelize(str2));
console.log(helpers.camelize(str3));
console.log(helpers.camelize(str4));
console.log(helpers.camelize(str5));
console.log(helpers.camelize(str6));

console.log("=============================");

// camelize object keys 
console.log(helpers.camelizeKeys(data));

console.log("=============================");

// camelize nested object keys
console.log(helpers.camelizeNestedKeys(nestedData));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert the nested object, then using lodash can be a bit painful.

I tried using regex, JSON.parse & JSON.stringify
and here is the code for the same

below code returns the new object that is having camel case instead of snake case

```
//input
var data = {
   'id': '123',
   'employee_name': 'John',
   'employee_type': {'new_name': 'foo'}  
};

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(
                /(_\w)\w+":/g,
                match => match[1].toUpperCase() + match.substring(2)
              ));

{
   'id': '123',
   'employeeName': 'John',
   'employeeType': {'newName': 'foo'}  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for keys with multiple underscores. For example "employee_full_name"

Answer (score 1):

Based on Abbos Tajimov's answer (and Ali's comment), we could also take advantage of [the arguments passed down to the inline function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).

```
const snakeToCamel = str => {
  if (!(/[_-]/).test(str)) return str

  return str.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/([-_])([a-z])/g, (_match, _p1, p2) => p2.toUpperCase())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
 _(data)
     .keys()
     .map(_.camelCase)
     .zipObject(_.values(data))
     .value()
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Mardok's version with nested objects, only issue is that it converts "null" to {}

here mine:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const toCamelCase: any = (obj: any) => {
    let rtn = obj
    if (typeof obj === 'object') {
        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            rtn = obj.map(toCamelCase)
        }
        else if (_.isEmpty(obj)) {
            rtn = null
        } else {
            rtn = {}
            for (let key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    const newKey = key.replace(/(_\w)/g, k => k[1].toUpperCase())
                    rtn[newKey] = toCamelCase(obj[key])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return rtn
}
```

Comment: No need for lodash here. You can simply add a check `&& obj !==null` in the first `if`

Answer (score 0):

Creates camelized object recursively.

```
function camelCase(obj) {
  const newObj = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = obj[key];
        const keyCamel = key.replace(/(\_\w)/g, (match) => match[1].toUpperCase());
        const isRecursive = typeof value === 'object';
        newObj[keyCamel] = isRecursive ? camelCase(value) : value;
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}

let data = {
  id: '123',
  employee_name: 'John',
  inner: {
    employee_type: 'new'
  },
}

camelCase(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found in typeorm repo https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/util/StringUtils.ts#L8

```
export function camelCase(str: string, firstCapital: boolean = false): string {
    return str.replace(
        /^([A-Z])|[\s-_](\w)/g,
        function (match, p1, p2, offset) {
            if (firstCapital === true && offset === 0) return p1
            if (p2) return p2.toUpperCase()
            return p1.toLowerCase()
        },
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value to input and the result will be camelcase:

```js
const snakeToCamel = input =>
  console.log(
    input.slice(0, input.indexOf('_')).toLowerCase() +
    input[input.indexOf('_') + 1].toUpperCase() +
    input.slice(input.indexOf('_') + 2)
  );
const inputs = [
  'underscore_case',
  'first_name',
  'Some_Variable',
  'calculate_AGE',
  'delayed_departure',
  'Hello_you',
  'hAI_i',
];
for (let input of inputs) {
  snakeToCamel(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have array inside your data you can use this code:

```js
const data = {
    vt_core_random: {
        user_details: {
        first_name: "xyz",
        last_name: "abc",
        groups: [
            {
            id: 1,
            group_type: "EXT"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            group_type: "INT"
            }
        ],
        address_type: {
            city_name: "nashik",
            state: {
            code_name: "MH",
            name: "Maharashtra"
            }
        }
        }
    }
    };
let newObject = {};
const rename = key => {
    if(key.includes("_")){
        return key.replace(/_([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
    }else return key
}
const convert = (data) => {
        if(typeof data === 'object'){

            if(Object.keys(data).length === 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                for (const key in data)
                {
                    const newKey = rename(key);
                    data[newKey] = data[key];
                    newKey !== key && delete data[key]
                    if(Array.isArray(data[newKey])) data[newKey].map(item => convert(item) )
                    else convert(data[newKey]) 
                }
            }
        }
    
}
convert(data);

console.log("Result: ", data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option without regex or other libs:

```js
const convertObjectFromSnakeCaseToCamelCase = (obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        delete obj[k];
        obj[camelCaseXMLFieldName(k)] = v;      
    });
    return obj;
}

const camelCaseXMLFieldName = (key) => {
    return key.toLowerCase().split("_").map(((part, i) => (i > 0) ? part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1) : part)).join("");
}

console.log(convertObjectFromSnakeCaseToCamelCase({
    'id': '123',
    'TEsT': 'Doe',
    'employee_name': 'John',
    'employee_type': 'new'
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

This function will recursively convert all snake case keys in the object to camelCase. Including objects within arrays and object within objects.

```
const convertSnakeCaseToCamelCase = (obj) => {
    let newObj = {};
    if (typeof(obj) !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        newObj = [];
    }
    for (const key in obj) {
        const childObj = convertSnakeCaseToCamelCase(obj[key]);
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            newObj.push(childObj);
        } else {
            const newKey = key.replace(/(\_\w)/g, (k) => k[1].toUpperCase());
            newObj[newKey] = childObj;
        }
    }
    return newObj;
};
```